# pushing data inside an existing empty array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Basically I have an main object dataToMovie, I have empty arrays. I want to display the content of the arr variable into mov[] and the content of the arr2 into ser[]. I have attempted to do something as you can see. I am looking to do this seperately for each array as I will have multiple data in the future

```
const dataToMovie = {
  createMovie,
  links: {
    mov: [],
    ser: [],
    rev: [],
    ext: [],
  },
};

const dataToInsert1 = {
  'model-10389': 164703,
  'model-10388': 164704,
  'model-10387': 164705,
};

const dataToInsert2 = {
  'model-10389': [1656, 1234, 1245],
  'model-10384': [1656, 1234, 1245],
  'model-10383': [1656, 1234, 1245],
};

const arr = Object.entries(dataToInsert1).map((entry) => ({
  id: entry[0].substring(6, entry[0].length),
  value: entry[1],
}));

//dataToMovie.links.mov[arr]

const arr2 = Object.entries(dataToInsert2).map(([key, value]) => ({
  modelId: key.substring(6),
  ids: value,
}));

//dataToMovie.links.ser[arr2]
```

Comment: you can use `concat`: dataToMovie.links.mov.concat(arr);

Comment: Arrays do have a `.push()` method to add things to them. You can even immediately push to it inside a foreach loop instead of mapping, if preferred.

Answer (score 1):

`concat` is a good candidate for this operation. it returns a merged array.

```
dataToMovie.links.mov = dataToMovie.links.mov.concat( arr )
dataToMovie.links.ser = dataToMovie.links.set.concat( arr2 )
```

Answer (score 0):

You are close. if the arrays are empty you can just do:

```
dataToMovie.links.mov = arr
dataToMovie.links.ser= arr2
```

If the arrays have items in them and you just want to add to them, you can use the spread operator

```
dataToMovie.links.mov = [...dataToMovie.links.mov, ...arr]
dataToMovie.links.ser = [...dataToMovie.links.ser, ...arr2]
```

Comment: I have a question, basically when I do dataToMovie.links.mov = arr  is it assigning "arr"  to the mov[] it seems like it is recreating a new object each time with the links object and mov array. is this recreating a new object ? I am looking only to insert the data inside, not recreating everything all the time.  Do you see what I mean